# com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats error when building AWS sumerian java project

Tags: java, android, amazon-sumerian

I have downloaded the following project from GIT amazon-sumerian-arcore-starter-app, with the intention of running it on my Android device to play around. I am not a Java programmer by nature, so have downloaded Android Studio for Windows in order to build and run the sample.

When I try to turn the source code into a 'module' (which I assume I need to do in order to run the code on a device as it expects a target module when you create a profile to run the code as, I get this error. I assume it's similar to missing a dll/library/reference in .NET C#? But I can't be sure. Anyone know how to address this issue? I would have expected the sample code to 'just work'.

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.counters.IndexCounters.<clinit>(IndexCounters.java:34)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.<init>(MapReduceIndex.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex$CompilerMapReduceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:214)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:73)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.<init>(JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.java:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.initialize(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.java:74)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexBuilder.buildStarted(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexBuilder.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:358)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:302)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:229)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745
```